# What does the saying "правда ваша" mean and is it used often?

Tags: переклад

The song [розмова](https://www.pisny.net/rozmova-pane-petlyuro) has the line Щось таки виросло, кажете?.. Так, правда ваша. What does this saying mean and in what contexts do Ukrainians say it?

Answer (score 3):

It is English "you're right" in fact (literally "the truth is yours"). But "маєте рацію" ("you've got a reason") is most recommended.

Answer (score 2):

> What does this saying mean and in what contexts do Ukrainians say it?

As [@Kumade](/users/6174) wrote [here](/a/7384/585), the phrase means *the truth is yours* where *yours* can be [depending on context] polite singular or plural *you*, while — for compare — *твоя* would for informal and singular *you*. Basically, itʼs a known [T–V distinction](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction).

And, yeah, today the phrase has less usage. Therefore if you say so then someone may think thatʼs a reference to or a type of joke based on the famous [Shevchenkoʼs work](//www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=708) where the such phrase exists and also basically known for everyone:

> А чванитесь, що ми Польщу
> Колись завалили!..
> *Правда ваша*: Польща впала,
> Та й вас роздавила!

Answer (score 1):

Щось таки виросло, кажете?.. Так, правда ваша.
You're saying something has grown after all?
Yes, you're right!
(таки ~after all)